# Docker-Machine,We can’t connect to the server at docker_machine_ip

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I keep following along with the book **Microservices with Docker, Flask and React** form [testdriven.io](https://testdriven.io/).

After creating and configuring a Container with flask, Postgres and running the following command `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d --build` everything looks fine but i can't access the webserver from host.

The output is

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container testdriven-app-users-db-1  Running  0.0s                                                       
 ⠿ Container testdriven-app-users-1     Started  1.1s
```

- when I go to the URL: **http://docker_machine_ip:5001/users/ping** this is what I should get:

```
{
    "message": "pong!",
    "status": "success"
}
```

But can't access the webserver and still don't understand the way?

- Dockerfile-dev

```
# base image
FROM python:3.9.12-alpine

# new
# install dependencies
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && \
    apk add netcat-openbsd

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# new
# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

- docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test

    depends_on:
      - users-db
  users-db:
    build:
      context: ./services/users/project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Comment: What does happen when you try to connect to that URL?  Does the application actually start up, and can you include a minimal working extract of the application proper in the question?  Where is the Docker Machine VM running?

Comment: Yeah, it does but I can't get                ```{    "message": "pong!",
    "status": "success"
}```

Comment: If you type `curl -v http://$(docker-machine ip):5001/users/ping` at the console, what does come back?  Is it a local VM, a cloud instance, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a network

```
networks:
  user_network:
```

then connect both using this network using

```
networks:
  - user_network
```

then you will need a `DATABASE_HOST="users-db"`(name of the container db)

you can then make use of this HOST in flask like

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['HOST'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST', 'users-db')
app.config['USER'] = <you know what it is>
app.config['PASSWORD'] = <you know what it is>
app.config['DB'] = <you know what it is>
```

you can now connect use the above info.

All together kind of looks likes below

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_HOST='users-db'
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
    networks:
      - user_network
    depends_on:
      - users-db
  users-db:
    build:
      context: ./services/users/project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - user_network
networks:
  user_network:
```

Comment: [Compose provides a network named `default`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for you and you don't need to manually declare one.  The `DATABASE_URL` in the question looks like it has the right host name already.